# Why is my dropdown menu appearing only halfway?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, frontend

I was creating a replica of google webpage. I have everything finished but my dropdown menu for the apps icon only shows up halfway. I've already tried increasing the height etc. I think its not showing after the header portion. Please suggest any possible blunders I may have committed.

**CSS**

```
<style>
.menu-btn 
{background-color:#f5f5f5 ;
 color: black;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 border: none;}

.dropdown-menu {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border:1% solid #3c4043;}

.menu-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   right: 0;
   align-items:center;
   border-radius: 3%;
   border:1% solid #black;
   width:300px;
   height: 500px;
   cursor: pointer;}
</style>

**<javascript>**

<script>
let dropdownBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuContent = document.querySelector('.menu-content');
dropdownBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   if(menuContent.style.display===""){
      menuContent.style.display="block";}
 else {
      menuContent.style.display="";}
})
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the  html code?

Comment: @Clvckl3s Its too large for me to put it here. but basically i was using rows and columns like this:```<div class="dropdown-menu">

             <button class="menu-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
      <div class="menu-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">```
            .....

Comment: why don't you edit the post and add the HTML code that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra : in the height for your menu-content class.

There are also a few other bugs in the CSS. I created a jsfiddle that might help you figure out what's wrong with your own code.

https://jsfiddle.net/6ck7rq53/6/

I created a simple HTML dropdown using your own classes:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <button class="menu-btn">Dropdown
        <div class="menu-content">
            <p>One</p>
            <p>Two</p>
            <p>Three</p>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I fixed your CSS bugs:

```
.menu-btn {
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 color: black;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 border: none;
 }

.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #3c4043;
  height: auto;
}

.menu-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   right: 0;
   align-items: center;
   border-radius: 3%;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 300px;
   height: 500px;
   cursor: pointer;
   left: 0; 
}
```